# AS3: How to force parameters in callback functions

Tags: actionscript-3, function, compiler-errors, parameters

I am currently doing something like this:

```
myFunc(tracer);

function tracer(message:String):void{
 trace(message);
}

function myFunc(callback:Function):void{
 callback("Hello");
}
```

Now, this works fine. But how can the function myFunc know, if the given callback function accepts the correct number and type of arguments in its signature?

I want to avoid that I call something like this somewhere in my code:

```
myFunc(tracer2);

function tracer2():void{
 trace("done");
}

function myFunc(callback:Function):void{
 // Argument mismatch!
 callback("Hello");
}
```

Is there a way to do something like this, in order to use compiler warnings/error messages and thus avoid exceptions at runtime?

```
// Won't work :-(
function myFunc(callback(message:String):Function):{
 callback("Hello");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that this is a situation that can only be caught at runtime. AS3 offers no mechanism for this kind of type-checking. I would suggest that if this is important, that you get compile-time checking by passing an object with a strongly typed interface rather than simply passing a function, where the type information you need will be lost.

Comment: Too bad :-(
Wished, AS3 was a bit more powerful.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can add a second parameter in `myFunc` that will give information on what parameters are expected to be sent to the callback function.
That way you could have `myFunc(tracer2,"null")` in one place and `myFunc(tracer,"String")` at another place.

I would try something like

```
function myFunc(callback:Function, ParamRequest:Array /* of String */ ):void{
}
```